# Why is this not working? Pushing a box using mouse pointer

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm a beginner in JavaScript, and trying to make a simple script that pushes a box using the mouse pointer, but unfortunately it isn't working for some reason, I hope you can help me out.

(This script is really primitive, only pushes the box from the left till now).

**index.html :**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Chase the box</title>
    <style>
        body {
        }

        .css-box{
            width : 100px;
            height : 100px;
            margin : auto;
            background-color : blue;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="box" class="css-box"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

**script.js :**

```
var box = document.getElementById("box");

var pushBox = function(e){
    if(e.pageX == box.offsetLeft){
        box.style.left = box.style.left + 1 + "px";
    }
};

document.addEventListener("mousemove" , pushBox);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`box.style.left` is a string. And in JavaScript if you do `string + int` the int will be type casted to a string and you get `string + string`. For instance, if `box.style.left` is `10px` you get:

```
'10px' + 1 + 'px'
  int typecasted to string
'10px' + '1' + 'px'
  create one string
'10px1px'
```

And that will be the value of `box.style.left`. That isn't what you want...

To solve this you can use `parseInt()`, which parses a string into an int:

```
box.style.left = parseInt(box.style.left) + 1 + "px";
```

And your if is only matching when the X position of the cursor is exactly the same pixel as `box.offsetLeft`. That's almost impossible, I don't know what you are trying to do with that if?

At least, `box.style.left` has no value the first time. You need to set the value at first to `0` and then use the event.

A working example will be: http://jsfiddle.net/WouterJ/enLwh/ (please note that I have added `position: relative;` because we can't use the `left` property on the current position)

---

Some more tips, since you are new to JS:

- If you do something like this:

  `X = X + 12;`

  You can short that up as:

  `X += 12;`

Comment: How is it not possible to do `e.pageX == box.offsetLeft` ? I've checked it to print both of them and at some point they match each other.
Another question, Why does `box.style.left` has no value at the beginning ? although I've tried to set `left = 50px` for example using css but still it has no value as i checked it. Why is that happening ? Thanks  a lot for the detailed answer and the tips :)

Comment: *"although I've tried to set left = 50px for example using css but still it has no value as i checked it. Why is that happening ?"* With `box.style` you get the style attribute, so you need to set it in the style attribute. *"How is it not possible to do e.pageX == box.offsetLeft ? I've checked it to print both of them and at some point they match each other."* I don't know what you want to do? Do you want to only move it when it is exactly the same? Then you are right, but I think you will something different.

Answer (score 2):

A JQuery version but accomplishes the same as you're trying to do

http://jsfiddle.net/3mxC3/1/

The main problem I can see with your script is that e.pageX == box.offsetLeft would mean that it's only going to be triggered when the pageX is exactly the offsetLeft.

The mousemove event won't be firing every pixel so this approach won't work. The easiest way to accomplish it is to set the mousemove onto the actual box instead (so it'll only fire if the user mouse overs the box)

Secondly, setting the left attribute on the box was doing nothing as the left/right-ness was being set by the margin: auto. Changing this to position: absolute makes it actually pay attention to the left attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a CSS `position` property other than `static` to the element so CSS `left` property can work.

```
.css-box{
     position: absolute;
     width : 100px;
     height : 100px;
     margin : auto;
     background-color : blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lastly you are better off adding stuff onload instead of having the script live in the body

Here is a script that lives in the head of the page, the rest of the issues are already solved by other ppl here

```
var pushBox = function(e){
    if(e.pageX >= box.offsetLeft){
        box.style.left = (parseInt(box.style.left,10) + 1) + "px";
    }
},box;
window.onload=function() {
  box = document.getElementById("box");
  document.addEventListener("mousemove" , pushBox);
}
```