# What's wrong with this javascript script?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mouseevent, mouseover

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Why is this not working ? pushing a box using mouse pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11594680/why-is-this-not-working-pushing-a-box-using-mouse-pointer)

This is a script to push a box using mouse pointer and it only work when the box is pushed from the left.

I've made an array to take positions of the mouse pointer and determine if it's going left or write.

Here's a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/smokn/BFQvn/) of what i got so far.

***index.js***

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Chase the box</title>
        <style>
            body {
            }

            .css-box{
                position: absolute ;
                top:20px;
                width : 100px;
                height : 100px;
                background-color : blue;
            }

            .css-textbox{
                margin-top: 500px;
            }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="box" class="css-box"></div>
        <div class="css-textbox">            
            <p>All : <input id="allTextbox" type="text"></input></p>
            <p>Left : <input id="leftTextbox" type="text"></input></p>
            <p>Right : <input id="rightTextbox" type="text"></input></p>
            <p>e.pageX(Left) : <input id="pageXTextbox" type="text"></input></p>
            <p>e.pageX(Right) : <input id="pageXRightTextbox" type="text"></input></p>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

***script.js***

```
var box = document.getElementById("box");
var allTextbox = document.getElementById("allTextbox");
var leftTextbox = document.getElementById("leftTextbox");
var rightTextbox = document.getElementById("rightTextbox");
var pageXTextbox = document.getElementById("pageXTextbox");
var PageXRightTextbox = document.getElementById("pageXRightTextbox");

Object.prototype.offsetRight = null;
  
var arr = [];
var pushBox = function(e){
    var pageXRight = window.innerWidth - e.pageX;
    box.offsetRight = window.innerWidth - (box.offsetWidth + box.offsetLeft);
    
    if(arr.length < 2){
        arr.push(e.pageX);
    } else {            
        if(arr[0] < arr[1]){
            if(e.pageX >= box.offsetLeft){
                box.style.left = e.pageX + "px";
            }
        } else if(arr[0] > arr[1]){
            if(pageXRight >= box.offsetRight){
                box.style.right = pageXRight + "px";
            }
        }
        
        arr.shift(arr[0] , arr[1]);        
    }
    
    allTextbox.value = window.innerWidth;
    leftTextbox.value = box.offsetLeft;
    rightTextbox.value = box.offsetRight;
    pageXTextbox.value = e.pageX;
    pageXRightTextbox.value = pageXRight;
}


document.addEventListener("mousemove" , pushBox);
```

Comment: Modifying `Object.prototype` is ***BAD***. **B  A  D**. It breaks jQuery for example and also any `for(var key in obj)` iteration that does not use `obj.hasOwnProperty(key)` checks (which are not necessary when iterating over plain objects assuming the environment is sane)

Comment: How is the different from the last two questions you asked? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11601419/trying-to-write-a-script-to-push-a-box-using-mouse-pointer-in-javascript and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11594680/why-is-this-not-working-pushing-a-box-using-mouse-pointer

Comment: @Rafael, i think you need a plus sign in there somewhere like this `var pageXLeft = window.innerWidth + e.pageX;`

Comment: @j08691 I've changed a lot in it. And really can't get it working so i'm trying to figure out how to get around it.

Answer (score 1):

Problem lies in two places:

1. You should not set both css attribute    left and    right at the same time, this would confuse the browser which should dictate the location.  If you set one, set the other to null.
2. See my comment below

I also slightly revised your script as     arr[0] and    arr[1] are not easy to read as they don't convey what they are, so I assign a variable to the array values for better readability.

Happy pushing.

```
var pushBox = function(e){
    var pageXRight = window.innerWidth - e.pageX;
    box.offsetRight = window.innerWidth - (box.offsetWidth + box.offsetLeft);

    if(arr.length < 2){
    arr.push(e.pageX);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
    } else {

    var previousX = arr[0];
    var newX = arr[1];

    if(previousX < newX){
                // add e.pageX <= box.offsetRight to ensure that mouse appearance to the right of the box would not push the box
        if(e.pageX >= box.offsetLeft && e.pageX <= box.offsetRight){
        box.style.right = null;
        box.style.left = e.pageX + "px";
        }
    } else if(previousX > newX){
        if(pageXRight >= box.offsetRight){
        box.style.left = null;
        box.style.right = pageXRight + "px";
        }
    }

    arr.shift(arr[0] , arr[1]);        
    }

    allTextbox.value = window.innerWidth;
    leftTextbox.value = box.offsetLeft;
    rightTextbox.value = box.offsetRight;
    pageXTextbox.value = e.pageX;
    pageXRightTextbox.value = pageXRight;
}
```

Comment: Well, it's half way there, but there's some strange behavior when you change the courser direction [see this](http://jsfiddle.net/BFQvn/2/)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean for the strange behavior, could you elaborate more?  Part of the odd of the behavior comes from the detection of "push" does not check if the cursor is at the same vertical position of the box.  So the cursor can "virtually" push the box even when it well at the bottom of the page.